# Ruby: delete an entry from a 2d array if it is not equal to a specific 1d array

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I'm having some trouble understanding the behavior of some code in Ruby. I want to match the contents of my 2d array with a specific 1d array.

```
s = [1,2,3].repeated_permutation(2).to_a
solution = [3,1]
s.each do |x|
    if x != solution
        puts s.length
        print "#{x}\n"
        s.delete(x)
    end
end
```

what I don't understand is that this code will return this:

```
s = [[1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 3]]
```

I am a beginner and I must be overlooking something basic. 
I did overcame this issue by circumventing it in a way that is surely not ideal:

```
s = [1,2,3].repeated_permutation(2).to_a
solution = [3,1]

s.each_with_index do |x,idx|
    if x != solution 
        s[idx] = nil
    end
end

=> [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,[3,1],nil]

s.flatten!.compact!

=> [3,1]
```

Can anyone tell me what would be a good Ruby way to perform this check?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `each` is deleting elements from `s`, 4 elements from the original 9 leaving `s` of length 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually [`Enumerable#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

```
[[1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 3]].detect { |e| e == [3, 1] }
#⇒ [3, 1]
```

The reason why your code returns the whole array is that `Enumerable#each` iterator returns the receiver itself. It’s not recommended to mutate enumerables during the enumerating process, it might lead to unpredicted/unexpected result. `each` drives crazy when the underlying array is changed.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [.select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) method, which can be used to select values from an array based on the evaluation of a block. For example:

```
s.select { |arry| arry == solution }
```

This will return an array containing the elements in `s` that match the `solution` array, e.g. `[[3,1]]`